# How to import a CLOB column into oracle from an excel file, using SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

I tried to import an excel file into a table and one of the column is CLOB.
Error message: import is not supported for CLOB datatype.

[image]

Is there any other method to import the file?

Comment: How many rows in the file?  write a vba script in Excel to do the inserts.

Comment: you're on an old version, upgrade to version 4.1. then on the import, set your import method to INSERT SCRIPT...it will built inserts and it should work for your CLOB text. I just tried it, and it worked...but not sure how large your CLOB text field is in the Excel column.

Comment: There are about 40,000 rows. The clob column has a string that varies from few hundred characters to few thousands.
I will update the software and try again.

Comment: I am getting this error message:
Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column